# Is there a way to return a table given a input in sqlite?

Tags: sql, function, sqlite, common-table-expression

I want to return the nth_value of a table given the value of an existing table column. But using that nested select affects the query's legibility: (ignore what demo is, just imagine that is a table with a sequential integer column ID)

```
WITH R (a,b) AS
(   
    VALUES(0, (SELECT first_value(ID) over() FROM demo))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a+1 as a, (SELECT nth_value(ID, a+1) over() FROM demo) FROM R WHERE a<10
)
SELECT * FROM R
```

This would be better if I could make some kind of function that maps a given input to a nth_value of demo. Something that could make this could be like:

```
WITH R (a,b) AS
(   
    VALUES(0, get_demo_nth_value(0) ) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a+1 as a, get_demo_nth_value(a+1) FROM R WHERE a<10
)
SELECT * FROM R
```

We cannot create user-defined functions in SQLite, but is there a workaround? Something like a function that doesn't need to be defined as a procedure or other thing to map a value to a table.

Comment: Have you tried manipulate this with rowid value? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Post sample data and expected results to explain better.